# NodeJS GCP pubsub publishing error: t.topic(...).publish is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to write data from my Node server to a pubsub topic that triggers a GCP Cloud Function. My code is more or less lifted straight from the [GCP Pubsub tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher).

However, I keep getting this error when I publish:

```
(node:60085) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: l.topic(...).publish is not a function
at /Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/dist/server.bundle.js:100:1697
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/kb/Documents/coding/maple/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

I've confirmed that no messages are getting sent to my Pubsub topic, and that my GCP function isn't getting triggered.

Here is my code:

```
var processedData = processResultsData(data);
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(processedData);
console.log("About to push to pubsub");
const messageId = await pubsub.topic(TOPIC_NAME).publish(dataBuffer);
console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
```

Comment: in your link to the tutorial, 'publish(...)' is not called directly after the topic(_). There is an **publisher()** between these two :  `topic(topicName).publisher().publish(dataBuffer, customAttributes)`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. You should post your comment as a question.

The weird thing is, the linked tutorial doesn't include call to publisher() like your line. Neither does the tutorial [git repo](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/topics.js). I'll create the PR with the changes if you'd rather not.

Comment: Tutorials can get out of date.  Maybe the APIs have changed.  File a bug report against it if you think it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is correct for the current version of the node client libraries (0.24.1).  My guess is that you have an old version of the client libraries installed.  Check which version is in your package.json, and set it to "latest" or "0.24.1".

Answer (score 0):

```
let message = {
    id : `your-unique-id`,
    data : [ {"key", "value"} , {"otherKey", "otherValue"} ]
  }

  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message));
  const messageId = await pubsub.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
  console.log('published : ', messageId );
```